# Get the File Type Description from batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am able to get the file name and extension by using the batch command:

for %%i in (*.*) do echo "%%~xi"

However I am wanting to get the descriptor.

For eg: for a file "foo.txt" I get ".txt" as a return argument.. I would want to get "TXT File (.txt)" instead.

Thanks,
Gautham

Answer (score 2):

```
assoc | find /i ".txt"
```

(more symbols to make answer valid)

Comment: Awesome! That worked.. Is there a shortcut for getting associations for multiple types? Like a .txt, .docx etc?? Thanks..

Comment: if with shortcut you mean one line yes - there's a way: `assoc | findstr /i /c:".txt=" /c:".doc="`

Comment: @Gautham - or even more simply: `assoc|findstr /il ".txt= .docx=". The /L option is important to force a literal match instead of regex.

Comment: Thanks npocmaka, Aacini and dbenham!

Answer (score 0):

The types shown by `assoc` command are not descriptive. You may define your own types this way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the desired types
set type[.txt]=TXT File (.txt)
set type[.doc]=Any description you want (.doc)
etc...

for %%i in (.) do echo File %%i: !type[%%~Xi]!
```